# Exporting data into new shapefile creates blank shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

I downloaded a Census Tract shapefile and joined Census data (as a CSV) to the shapefile. I checked the attribute table and I see that my joined data is present and the join worked correctly.

However, when I go to Export Data and export it as a new shapefile, it returns a blank shapefile with zero records. I have done this process a hundred times before and have never had this issue. What is wrong?

Comment: Spatial extent in environment settings?